# Database Design for Time Table Generation

Tags: mysql, sql, jakarta-ee, database-design, timetable

I am doing a project using J2EE(servlet) for Time Table Generation of College.
There are Six Slots(6 Hours) in a Day

```
    4 x 1 HR Lectures
    1 x 2 HR Lab
```

There Are three batches ( 3IT, 5IT, 7IT)

```
   2 Classroom 
   1 LAB
```

Each slot in the time table will have

```
       (Subject,Faculty)
```

For Lab I will duplicate the slot.
The Tables

```
    Subject(SubjectID  INT, SubjectName VARCHAR);
    Faculty(FacultyID INT,FacultyName VARCHAR,NumOfSub INT,Subjects  XYZ);
```

Here I am not able to decide the `DATATYPE` for subject. What should I do ? Since a faculty can teach multiple subjects ? Also how to link with Subject Table ?

P.S. Using MySQL Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to actually store either `NumOfSub` (number of subjects) **OR** `Subjects` in `Faculty`.  Storing subjects that way is a violation of [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), and dealing with it would cause *major* headaches.
Instead, what you want is another table:

```
FacultySubject
----------------
FacultyId  -- fk for Faculty.FacultyId
SubjectId  -- fk for Subject.SubjectId
```

From this, you can easily get the count of subjects, or a set of rows listing the subjects (I believe MySQL also has functions to return a list of values, but I have no experience with those):
This query will retrieve the count of Subjects taught by a particular teacher:

```
SELECT Faculty.FacultyId, COUNT(*)
FROM Faculty
JOIN FacultySubject
  ON FacultySubject.FacultyId = FacultyId.FacultyId
WHERE Faculty.FacultyName = 'Really Cool Professor'
GROUP BY Faculty.FacultyId
```

... and this query will get all the subjects (named) that they teach:

```
SELECT Subject.SubjectId, Subject.SubjectName
FROM Faculty
JOIN FacultySubject
  ON FacultySubject.FacultyId = FacultyId.FacultyId
JOIN Subject
  ON Subject.SubjectId = FacultySubject.SubjectId
WHERE Faculty.FacultyName = 'Really Cool Professor'
```

(note that this last returns the subjects as a set of rows ie:

```
SubjectId    SubjectName
=========================
1            Tree Houses
2            Annoying Younger Sisters
3            Swimming Holes
4            Fishing
```

)

Comment: Then FacultySubject subject table will contain  data like this right ??    IT101  ABC  IT102 ABC

Comment: No - it'll only hold the fk links to the existing ids, which you've indicated are integers; it'll be totally opaque, something like `1 1, 2 3, 88 1`.  In order to get the actual 'display' data (as internal database ids should rarely/never escape), you're going to need to join to the other tables.  One presumes `IT101` is in `Subject`, and `ABC` is in `Faculty`.

Comment: thx now got it ``CREATE TABLE `facsub` (
  `fid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `fid_idx` (`fid`),
  KEY `sid_idx` (`sid`),
  CONSTRAINT `sid` FOREIGN KEY (`sid`) REFERENCES `subject` (`sid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fid` FOREIGN KEY (`fid`) REFERENCES `faculty` (`fid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
``  is the `create` sql query foe=r `FacultySubject`, `fid` and '`sid` are FacultyID and StudentID

Comment: You probably  want a unique-key constraint on the pair of values, so you don't get duplicates (usually, you don't want duplicate values in tables), but you got it.  You'll have multiple of the same subject and faculty, of course.  Oh, and if the DB supports it, don't use short/cryptic table names, or quoted identifiers.

Comment: thanks @Clockwork-Muse .. I am now able to add data to FacultySubject by taking each faculty and adding their corresponding subjects. Can you tell me which normal form is my Database ??

Comment: Given the limited amount of information I have, if you've followed my recommendations these tables should end up in 3rd (note that most dbs will end up gravitating toward that with some minimal design effort).  It's not actually a good idea to design to hit a normal form - especially as many real-world systems need to selectively de-normalize for performance reasons; it's better to design for stuff like limiting duplication, etc, and the normal form pops out.  Oh, if this answer was what you needed, please accept it by clicking the check-mark on the left.